# Is there any way(e.g. software etc.) where data can be matched visually

Tags: microsoft-excel, software-rec, database, data-validation, database-administration

I have two columns in excel(see N.B.) that contain as below

```
Column1          Column2
-------         --------
USA              India
Serbia           United States of America
Bharat           China
Chin             Former Yugoslavia
```

And now matching them visually -e.g.

[image: demo]

Now i want a way (in excel or outside of excel) to match two columns visually i.e. drawing arrows- after all arrows will give me a matched table/data and this data will be used in excel.

1. I tried Fuzzymatch for excel but since my data is not regular so it
   **fails**.
2. I am unwilling to use index-match/lookup function since it is **not**
   **applicable** in this case.
3. Drop-down list is so small and needs many scrolling and **all** **values**
   need to be memorized before selecting- after all it is **slow**
   too.

---

N.B. I am open to transfer data to another system(software/format etc.) for the sake of matching visually- but of course matched data to be imported into excel for further analysis.

Comment: There is no way for that in Excel to recognize visible information. Best workarounds you can use is to use a new column where you add column1 data as drop-down list in data validation, so you can select it easily. Or you can use a helper column where you enter row number of desired match in column1, then get the correct value with `Match()`. In both cases you can combine your solution with conditional formatting to visually mark already selected items.

Comment: @MátéJuhász yeah! i tried `index-match` duo but entering matching row- number is boring and thus error prone again of less confidence, finally it hard to check/showing others  comparing visual.

Comment: what about drop-down list?

Comment: Drop-down list is so small and needs many scrolling and all values need to be clenched in my head before selecting.